# App bar not pushed up when focused on edit text field

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have a static image on appbar and below that I am using scrollView which contain my edit text.So the problem is that when I focus on edit text soft keyboard hide my fields.It can't push the app bar image up.I try using   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustUnspecified" all these combination but it didn't work .Can any one suggest better way out.

my root view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register_simplify"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="org.tta.mobile.view.Register_simplify">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:expanded="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="413dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mx_header_banner">
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--Tab layout-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:id="@+id/register_simplified_tablayout_ll_id"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/mx_signup_signin_top_tablayout_height"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#22d2c5"
        android:id="@+id/mRegisteractivityTabs">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="SIGN-IN"

            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and my view inside pageviewer which contain fields

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mx_sign_up_fragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="org.tta.mobile.mx_views.SignUpFragment">

    <!--android:paddingTop="@dimen/mx_scroll_view_top_padding"-->

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/registrationLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/manprax_sign_in_Layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/message_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <include layout="@layout/panel_message_with_check" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/required_fields_layout_register"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mx_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

       <!-- <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:id="@+id/mx_signup_remember_me_layout" >

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/mx_signup_remember_me_Chkbx"
                android:text="Remember me"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
        </FrameLayout>-->

    <FrameLayout
     style="@style/edX.Widget.Sign_In_Manprax_Layout"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/mx_btn_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id="@+id/send_OTP_button_layout"
        android:contentDescription="@string/create_account_btn">

        <TextView
            style="@style/edX.Widget.SignInButton"
            android:id="@+id/send_OTP_tv"
            android:text="@string/send_OTP_text" />
        <include layout="@layout/button_progress_indicator" />
    </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: post your screenshot also

Comment: Thats  my Root activity where i am using applayout and a page viewer ...inside page view I am using fragmnet which contain Relative with scroll view and fields inside it..